# How to solve the issue - please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities

Tags: php, symfony, intl

What i Need

- I'm implementing  currency symbol using symfony.
- I  have referred this link : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html.

The code i have implemented:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;
                
\Locale::setDefault('en');
$currencies = Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencyNames();

$currency = Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencyName('INR');

$symbol = Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('INR');

$fractionDigits = Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getFractionDigits('INR');

$roundingIncrement = Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getRoundingIncrement('INR');
```

Error:

> The Symfony\Component\Intl\Locale\Locale::setDefault() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - MethodNotImplementedException

OS configuration:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="13.04, Raring Ringtail"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.04"
VERSION_ID="13.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

- I have referred this link for intln installation http://php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php.

Comment: What OS (in case of linux, please tell us the distribution) do you run?

Comment: i have updated configuration

Comment: For Windows OS: see my answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730747/1005741

Answer (score 26):

### UPDATED for new versions of PHP:

You can install `intl` extension for your current php version by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

If you need to install `php-intl` not only for current selected PHP-version you can pass php version right after `php` word:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl    # for PHP version 7.4
sudo apt-get install php8.1-intl    # for PHP version 8.1
```

If you use Apache server with `mod_php` don't forget to restart it:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

### Original Answer

You need just put one line to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-intl

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install libicu48` and then again install `intl`

Comment: bts@bts:~$ sudo apt-get install libicu48
[sudo] password for bts: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libicu48 is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
bts@bts:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-intl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-intl

Comment: Ok. Try do it more manually: `pear channel-update pear.php.net`

`pear upgrade PEAR`

`pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`

`pear install intl`

Comment: bts@bts:~$ pear channel-update pear.php.net
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date

Comment: bts@bts:~$ pear upgrade PEAR pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
WARNING: configuration download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.4.9/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pear.php.net" is not writeable by the current user
bts@bts:~$ pear install intl

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/intl" - package pecl/intl can be installed with "pecl install intl"
install failed

Comment: You need first to clean your other issues. Disable `imap.so` and try again.

Comment: No matter your problem in life, there is always an apt-get install solution ;-)

Comment: I have that installed, but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 17):

Extending the Answer by `Michael Sivolobov`, for php7 on debian 9 /stretch

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

or simply

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Thanks!

Comment: Package 'php-intl' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 8):

If you are using XAMPP on windows here is how:

open for example c:\xampp\php\php.ini and remove the semi colon ";" in front of "extension=php_intl.dll" save the file and restart apache.

That will get solve the error message.

Done.

Answer (score 4):

If someone facing this issue in docker mode, for docker instances of `php8.x` please use this

```
docker-php-ext-install intl
```

Comment: Very nice, thx you its work for me !

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to install **intl** on Ubuntu 16.04 with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

I've got an error like:

> error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or no failed. Please verify ICU
>   install prefix and make sure icu-config works. ERROR:
>   `/tmp/pear/temp/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
>   --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT' failed

In order to solve the problem I needed to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

and after that install

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open XAMPP server.
click on Apache `config` button
And open `php.ini` file.
[image]
Under `php.ini` file search `intl`
And uncommented out the line.
And restart the server.
[image]
Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For docker image php:5.6-apache this solved the problem for me

> So I added these to my config:

```
  - run: sudo apt-get update
  - run: sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++
  - run: sudo docker-php-ext-configure intl
  - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install intl
```

Reference: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/cannot-install-php-intl-on-php7-2-image/20528/5

Answer (score 0):

For docker with fpm it is:

```bash
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl
```

Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/243663/739270