# Sf2 “money” field type: decimal separator and locale

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony application that I develop on OS X and deploy to Debian Jessie, both running PHP 5.6.12. The Symfony (standard edition) version is the same on both systems: 2.7.3. The translator service is not enabled, the `default_locale` is set to `de` (German) on both systems, and there are no configuration differences in respect to I18n or locale handling.

In this application, there is a form that uses the “money” field type, with the `currency` set to `EUR`. On OS X, the field value is displayed with comma as decimal separator (as it is common in German) and with the “€” symbol after the field. On Debian Jessie, the decimal separator is a dot, and the “€” symbol is displayed left to the field. This behavior is the same for clients sending different “Accept-Language” request headers.

My questions are:

- What can I do to make the Debian installation behave like the OS X installation, i.e. respect the `de` locale? Or asked differently: where might the difference in behavior come from?
- The Sf2 documentation says “Depending on the currency - the currency symbol may be shown before or after the input text field.” On both systems, the currency is the same, but yet the behavior differs, so I guess the documentation is inaccurate. Or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm facing very same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Do you have exactly the same setup?

Comment: No, I am developing on Windows and deploying on Ubuntu server. I didn't find global solution, tried setting locale globally and some other options - didn't help. So lastly I decided to use transformer + custom field type where I just replacing dot separator with comma. Not the best solution, but for now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that the php-intl extension is installed.

Because the [Symfony Intl Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html), which is a replacement layer for a missing php-intl extension only supports the locale: 'en', which you can see in [their php files](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/NumberFormatter/NumberFormatter.php).

```
public function __construct($locale = 'en', $style = null, $pattern = null)
{
    if ('en' !== $locale && null !== $locale) {
        throw new MethodArgumentValueNotImplementedException(__METHOD__, 'locale', $locale, 'Only the locale "en" is supported');
    }
    ....
}
```

And also because an [exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26602923/663551), if you try to call the following code.

```
\Locale::setDefault('de_DE');
```

> The Symfony\Component\Intl\Locale\Locale::setDefault() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - MethodNotImplementedException

As the answer in the above linked Stackoverflow question states, you have to install php-intl. For me on Ubuntu somehow, that PHP-5 and PHP-7 is available was a problem. PHP5-intl was installed but not PHP7-intl. You should make sure by calling **phpinfo();** that the extension is really loaded.

My answer assumes, that you have a locale configured in symfony, as I have done in the following lines:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%", 'en'] }
    default_locale: de
```

The twig derivate in the symfony configuration also supports the following (for our issue unneccessary) entries:

```
date:
    format: d.m.Y, H:i:s
    interval_format: '%%d Tage'   
    timezone: Europe/Paris
number_format:
    decimals: 2
    decimal_point: ','
    thousands_separator: '.'
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Unfortunately, 10 days ago I relocated the project to a different server, so I cannot test if that was the real cause, but I verified that on the old server, the `intl` extension was missing, but on the new one (where the problem is not observable), `intl` is present, as it is on the OS X system. Therefore, it makes absolute sense to assume that this caused the issue.