# Change decimalseparator for a specific Language

Tags: php, symfony, intl

In Russian language there is no fixed definition for the *decimal separator character* (GOST 8.417-2002 and GOST 2.004-88 - Russian state standards). The `,` (comma) is recommended but `.` (point) is possible.

The *intl* Extension in php defines the `,` (comma) as the decimal separator for Russian language.

I want to change the decimal separator character depend on users preference.

In my project I have an listener `onKernelRequest` where I set the locale. I assume this is the place where to change the predefined `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL`.

```
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        } 
        if ($locale == 'ru_RU') {
            // set NumberFormatter::DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL = '.' 
        }
}
```

Comment: can you not just use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)?

Comment: This answer might provide what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38575177/457268

Comment: @DevDonkey: in principle yes, but then I have to touch each place where the function number_format() is used. and have to decide if I have to change the standard values (`language == 'ru_RU'`) or not (`language != 'ru'RU'`).

Comment: @K0pernicus: the answer you mention did not suit to my problem. There one make a global twig setting. I'm want to make this setting depend on the selected language (and a user preference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use setlocale (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) to set the locale globally.

But I dont think we can change the decimal separator globally. Php fetches the locale information from the operating system. I did not find any option that allows the locale information to be updated.

One option is that you use a different locale for currency and a different locale for date/time, language etc. For example if your user selects Russian as their language, you can call setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US'). This will force Php to use the American locale for formatting numbers

Comment: I have found an work around for my problem. I have created a twig extension that override the **localizedcurrency** filter function:

`public function localizedcurrency($number, $currency = null, $locale = null)
{
    $formatter = twig_get_number_formatter($locale, 'currency');
    if ($formatter->getLocale() == 'ru') {
        $formatter->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::MONETARY_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, '.');
    }
        
    return $formatter->formatCurrency($number, $currency);
}`