# how can I enable PHP Extension intl?

Tags: xampp, magento2, php-5.6

I am going to install Magento2 at my local server and it gives me following error notice.

[image: error at PHP extension intl]

I am using XAMPP. When I tried to enable it from php.ini file it throws another error for missing dll:

> The program can't start because MSVCP110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

[image: Missing MSVCP110.dll]

Any help?

Comment: Have you enable in php and apache php.ini ?

Comment: Add C:\xampp\php to PATH and try again!

Comment: duplicated issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602923/how-to-solve-the-issue-please-install-the-intl-extension-for-full-localizati/45765112#45765112

Comment: For PHP-7: 
extension=intl

Answer (score 144):

First of all stop the xampp/wamp and then kindly remove the starting semicolon ( **;** ) from your **xampp/php/php.ini** the following code.

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

And then restart your xampp/wamp.

Comment: Please check this the answer. tested with xampp-win32-5.6.19-0-VC11-installer. thanks Raham.

Comment: @ vaghani janak kindly stop your xampp/wamp first and then change in the directed file and restart your xampp/wamp.

Comment: Dear @Savan Dholu please let me know what paltform you are using...mean operating system...

Comment: @Raham Thanks for reply 
i am using windows 7 64bit

Comment: Dear @Savan Dholu please stop all the services.Make changes in php.ini as administrator & then restart your xampp. And sorry for late reply.

Comment: in my case also need add these line without semicolumns to php.ini --> ;extension=pcre.so
also ;extension=spl.so

Comment: In my case it was named extension=intl Xampp v3.2.4

Comment: the latest fix is removing the `;` from `;extension=intl`

Answer (score 86):

I wrote this post if anyone come across this question for PrestaShop, I don't know if it will work for Magento2. I solved enabling PHP extension intl for the PrestaShop installation by:

1. Open XAMPP Control Pane.
2. Stop the Apache server if it was started.
3. Then from **Config** button click on **PHP (php.ini)** item.

[image]

4. Php.ini will open in Notepad (or a default text editor), click Ctrl + F and search for **;extension=intl** and remove the semicolon.

[image]

5. Then save and close Notepad and re-start the Apache server.

These steps for me solved the issue.

**Note (2):** 
I'm using XAMPP v3.2.3 and PrestaShop v1.7.5.1

[image]

Comment: Nice ! it's work

Answer (score 30):

**If you are using ubuntu** you can take update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install extension in case of **php 5.6**

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl
```

And in case of **php 7.0**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

And in case of **php 8.1**

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-intl
```

And restart your apache after

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And restart your nginx after

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

**If you are using xampp** then remove semicolon ( ; ) in **xampp/php/php.ini** from below line

```
 ;extension=php_intl.dll
```

And then restart your xampp.

Comment: Worked on Linux.

Answer (score 25):

I was also having the same issue, and just now i got it ***solved***.
Please try the bellow steps to get it solved:

- Open php.ini and remove semicolon (;) from  `;extension=php_intl.dll`
- When you try to restart the apache it will through some errors, that might be because of some .dll files. Simply copy all the **icu****.dll** files

From

> Xampp folder/php

To

> Xampp folder/apache/bin

- Still i was getting msvcp110.dll file missing error. I have downloaded this missing file from [Here](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcp110) and put that in desired location

> For windows 7 32 bit it is - C:\Windows\System32

- Now Start Apache and it is working fine.

Comment: copying icu****.dll  to apache/bin helps.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with PHP 7.2.0, you only need to specify the extension name.

I.e., **add the following line to your `php.ini`**:

```
extension=intl
```

See PHP's [docomentation on loading extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/de/install.pecl.windows.php#install.pecl.windows.loading) for more informations.

Answer (score 9):

I have seen the screen shoot, the issue you are having is missing msvcp110.dll , this file you can download from

https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp110.dll.html

and upload to **C:/Windows** folder

than after edit php.ini from **XAMPP**

Change

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Save the file and restart Apache from **XAMPP**

Answer (score 8):

For Megento Installation you Need to

1. Stop Apache Service
2. uncomment the **extension=php_intl.dll** in php.ini file.
3. copy all 6 files icudt57.dll,icuin57.dll,icuio57.dll,icule57.dll,iculx57.dll,icuuc57.dll From **php** folder to **apache\bin**
   Now Restart you apache service

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is go to php.ini in your xampp folder (xampp\php\php.ini) and remove ; from ;extension=php_intl.dll

> ;extension=php_intl.dll

TO

> extension=php_intl.dll

Answer (score 5):

Simply copy all icu****.dll files from

C:\xampp\php

to

C:\xampp\apache\bin

[or]

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12

to

C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9

intl extension will start working!!!

Comment: great response , using yetiforce

Answer (score 5):

**ADDITIONAL NOTE** (As this is very old question and has no accepted answer yet)

I am on [xampp-win32-7.2.3-0-VC15-installer](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.2.3/xampp-win32-7.2.3-0-VC15-installer.exe) on Windows10-64bit.

here is the notes I see in my php.ini file.

> **Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=.so' and
> ; 'extension='php_.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
> ; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
> ; move to the new ('extension=) syntax.**

So you will only find the extension name as `intl` instead of `php_intl.dll` and then uncommenting that line should work (It worked for me atleast).

> extension=intl

Answer (score 4):

I was having same kind of problem with ldap, intl, curl php extensions. I've solved those issues by the following ways:

**At first** you've to check whether these extensions have been enabled in the php.ini file by removing semicolon (;) in front of the following lines:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

**Secondly,** libeay32.dll, ibssh2.dll and ssleay32.dll files have to be loaded by php properly to function those extensions properly. These dll files are required by several php extensions (ie curl, ldap, intl etc). These files generally reside in the php installation directory [for my case it is C:\php directory]. 
Additionally, for intl extension to be enabled you're gonna need some other dll files to be loaded by php properly. The name of these files begin with icu (ie icudt57.dll icuin57.dll etc for php version 5.6). You'll also find these files in the php main installation directory.

There is a alternate way you can load these files from your httpd.conf (apache configuratio file) file instead of copying them to the apache's bin directory. This can be done by using the following technique:

Please note that my php version is 5.5.

```
LoadFile  "C:/php/icudt51.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/icuin51.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/icuio51.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/icule51.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/iculx51.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/icutest51.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/icutu51.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/icuuc51.dll"

LoadFile  "C:/php/libeay32.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/libssh2.dll"
LoadFile  "C:/php/ssleay32.dll"

 That's it.
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found two errors during the installing of Magento to localhost.
There are PHP Extension xsl and intl and I have solved the issue by following steps.

1. Open php.ini
2. Remove '#' cha from the lines extension=php_xsl.dll and extension=php_intl.dll.
3. Save the file and restart xamp again
4. Click Try Again on Magento installation page.

Then all the things were passed as well as following picture.

[image: Solving php extension error for php_xsl and php_intl]

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to C:\xampp\php
2. open the file "php.ini-development" on a text editor.
3. Then uncomment ;extension=php_intl.dll by removing the semicolon

Answer (score 3):

Use `phpinfo()` function to find `php.ini` file path,
open php.ini file. Here search `extension=php_intl.dll` then remove semi-colon (`;`) beginning of that line.

After removing semi-colon (`;`) restart you webserver (apache).

Answer (score 2):

For enable PHP Extension intl , follow the Steps..

1. Open the xampp/php/php.ini file in any editor.
2. Search ";extension=php_intl.dll"
3. kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; )

Like : `;extension=php_intl.dll` -> `extension=php_intl.dll`

4. Save the xampp/php/php.ini file.
5. Restart your xampp/wamp

Hope its work..Cheers..

Answer (score 2):

On My windows I just opened Xampp control panel then on Apache Module same line I clicked on Config then it shows all reconfigured files then choose

```
PHP (php.ini)
```

the file will be opened in text editor like notepad then search for extension you want then change

`;extension=php_intl.dll` -> `extension=php_intl.dll`

That's all hope it will work

Answer (score 2):

Enable the intl extension in the php.ini file.

Under Apache, click config.

[image]

Click php.ini.

[image]

ctrl + f to search intl to find the extension.

[image]

Remove the semi-colon to enable the extension. (This is something that wasn't self explanatory to me at first).

[image]

Save the file. Restart your apache server in xampp. The error should now be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is all command lines to install magento2

**PHP Extension xsl and intl.  CMD**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
sudo php5enmod xsl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**PHP Extension mcrypt.  CMD**

```
sudo updatedb 
locate mcrypt.ini
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

If the below line is not available or commented in C:\xampp\php\php.ini, then add it or uncomment and restart the apache server then it works.

> extension=php_intl.dll

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to stop your server and
go to this path **xampp/php/php.ini** and find this `;extension=php_intl.dll` and then you need to remove the semicolon ( ; ) from the following code and save the file.

And then restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Laminas, I got the same error message

> "Translator component requires the intl PHP extension"

while wanting to view the web application with the php web server:

> php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php

As I'm usgin XAMPP, in

> c:\xampp\php\php.ini

I had to enable the PHP extension intl in this line `;extension=php_intl.dll`, remove the starting semicolon (;) and restart XAMPP. I hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

i had this prob but solved !
   enable the extension=php_intl.dll 
now if you restart XAMPP this error will popup "msvcp110.dll is missing form your computer"

for solving this error: download this file from : https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp110.dll.html
then put this file to **C:windows** and then restart xampp it will works.

Answer (score -1):

For instalation of magento on local host you need to uncomment the extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and copy all icudt57.dll,icuin57.dll,icuio57.dll,icule57.dll,iculx57.dll,icuuc57.dll files from php folder to XAMPP\apache\bin folder.

Then Restart the xamp server