# PHP Extension intl. missing for magento v 2.0.4

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to install `Magento v2.0.4.`, but unfortunately I am getting below PHP Extensions error :

> 1 missing PHP extensions.

Then I uncommented extension `php_intl.dll`, copy from `xampp/php - icudt51.dll 8files` to paste `xampp/apache/bin`. 
Then I restarted xampp. But no luck, error is the same.

Could you please help me?

Comment: i don't remember that u have to copy paste any file. just uncomment ;extension=php_intl.dll. 

If restating xampp not working , try a restart ( PC ). or u can try uninstalling services for windows startup , u can try uninstalling them .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i enable PHP Extension intl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)