# I have install Magento2 at my local system, and it gives me following error notice as "PHP Extension xsl". How Can I fix this Issues

Tags: php, magento

How can I fix this issues. Please help to me. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: have you thought about *installing the missing extension*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i enable PHP Extension intl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open yor `php.ini` (For xampp `xampp/php/php.ini`)
- Find text `extension=php_xsl.dll`
- Uncomment this line (By removing semicolon ';')
- Restart xampp and refresh page it will works

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the XSLT Processor: http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php