# Can't enable the php-intl module

Tags: php, apache, yum, php-5.6

I have installed php56-php-intl.x86_64 successfully, however it is not enabled.

What I have done for check is like these below.

yum list installed | grep php

```
[koara@jp2 html]$ yum list installed | grep php

php.x86_64                               5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-cli.x86_64                           5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-common.x86_64                        5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-devel.x86_64                         5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-doctrine-instantiator.noarch         1.0.5-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-fedora-autoloader.noarch             0.2.1-2.el6.remi           @remi       
php-mbstring.x86_64                      5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-mcrypt.x86_64                        5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-myclabs-deep-copy.noarch             1.5.5-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                       5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-opcache.x86_64                       5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-pdo.x86_64                           5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-pear.noarch                          1:1.10.1-8.el6.remi        @remi       
php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64                    1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6      @remi-php56 
php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64              1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6      @remi-php56 
php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64                   2.5.0-1.el6.remi.5.6       @remi-php56 
php-pecl-xhprof.x86_64                   0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6       @remi-php56 
php-pecl-zip.x86_64                      1.13.5-1.el6.remi.5.6      @remi-php56 
php-phpdocumentor-reflection-docblock.noarch
php-phpspec-prophecy.noarch              1.6.2-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-File-Iterator.noarch         1.4.2-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-PHP-CodeCoverage.noarch      4.0.4-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-PHP-Invoker.noarch           1.1.4-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-PHP-Timer.noarch             1.0.8-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-PHP-TokenStream.noarch       1.4.9-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-PHPUnit.noarch               5.7.5-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-PHPUnit-MockObject.noarch    3.4.3-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-Text-Template.noarch         1.2.1-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-Version.noarch               2.0.1-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-comparator.noarch            1.2.2-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-diff.noarch                  1.4.1-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-environment.noarch           2.0.0-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-phpunit-exporter.noarch              2.0.0-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-process.x86_64                       5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-sebastian-code-unit-reverse-lookup.noarch
php-sebastian-global-state.noarch        1.1.1-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-sebastian-object-enumerator.noarch   2.0.0-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-sebastian-recursion-context.noarch   2.0.0-1.el6.remi           @remi       
php-sebastian-resource-operations.noarch 1.0.0-2.el6.remi           @remi       
php-soap.x86_64                          5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php-symfony-class-loader.noarch          2.8.15-3.el6.remi          @remi       
php-symfony-common.noarch                2.8.15-3.el6.remi          @remi       
php-symfony-yaml.noarch                  2.8.15-3.el6.remi          @remi       
php-xml.x86_64                           5.6.29-1.el6.remi          @remi-php56 
php56-php-common.x86_64                  5.6.30-1.el6.remi          @remi       
php56-php-intl.x86_64                    5.6.30-1.el6.remi          @remi       
php56-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64              1.3.10-1.el6.remi          @remi       
php56-php-pecl-zip.x86_64                1.13.5-1.el6.remi          @remi       
php56-runtime.x86_64                     2.1-5.el6.remi             @remi
```

php56-php-intl.x86_64 looks correctly installed.

However

`php -m | grep intl`

doesn't show anything.

I have restarted apache server already, what can I do next??

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl) out. Nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your output, PHP 5.6 is installed from **remi-php56** repository, so you have to install **php-intl** from the same repository (which doesn't seems enabled), not **php56-php-intl** which is a different package for parallel installation.

Have you read the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) ?

In short

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum install php-intl
```

As remi-php56 only provides PHP 5.6 and its extensions, it is safe to be enabled permanently if you use. More it will allow to get new updates (current is 5.6.30, not 5.6.29)