# Rediness check of "PHP Extension intl" not working despite trying everything

Tags: php, magento, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to install Magento for the first time. I have extracted all the Magento Files to ...htdocs/magento/. So, the rediness check shows "PHP Extension intl." Error. I have tried everything. When I remove "**;**" from **;extension=php_intl.dll**, copy all the six icu...DLL files to apache/bin/  my localhost refuses to connect.

[image: All six Icu...Dll files]

[image: When I remove the comment, localhost refuses to connect]

When I comment the **extension=php_intl.dll** again and restart the server, localhost starts working but rediness check will still show the missing "intl DLL" error.Please, Help me solve this.

I am using BITNAMI WAMPSTACK, Windows 7, and downloaded magento from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

I can't even stop or restart servers because it shows error while doing so..[image: Error Stopping Servers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add separate lines for 6 file!

if it is still not working, you should check your error log on your server

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "You should try to add separate lines for 6 file!" ? Do you mean to say that I should write "extension=icudt57.dll" and similar 5 lines in my php notepad file?

Comment: @NishantSharma yes, sorry about my bad English :)

Comment: have you tried with this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl

if it is still not working, you should check your php version

Comment: The packages at http://windows.php.net/download/ all contain the php_intl.dll which is located in the subdir ext/.
All you have to do is to check if your extension_dir points to the right directory and add (or uncomment) the extension=php_intl.dll directive.

Comment: i think you don't have php_intl.dll in library ^^

Comment: I've checked that link. Actually I'm not getting any " msvcp110.dll " error. I think the problem is that I cannot stop or restart the servers. For that I have to restart my whole system. So, what I do is that, I open the php folder and do the changes in my php configuration file, save it and restart the system. And, this doesn't work. My PHP version is 7.1.13

Comment: Okay, So my issue got solved. Actually I didn't have the administrator privilege to login. Hence, I couldn't stop or start the servers. So, i contacted the admins and then stopped the servers, removed ";" , restarted the servers and the issue got solved. Thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So my issue got solved. Actually I didn't have the administrator privilege to login. Hence, I couldn't stop or start the servers. So, i contacted the admins and then stopped the servers, removed ";" , restarted the servers and the issue got solved.