# How enable lampp(Xampp) php extension in in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-extension, lampp

I installed xampp on my ubuntu 18.04 machine. Now I need to enable some extension that is not enabled by default. I found php.ini file but can't figure it our where should i place the .so file.

There is a question asked here before for windows, and I think extension enabling is different in linux machine than windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i enable PHP Extension intl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

Comment: No it's not, that is for windows and mine is Linux