# Unable to install Magento 2 on my localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: php, magento2

Iam trying to install Magento 2.2.4 on my local machine, but facing the issue "PHP Extension intl is missing"(screenshot attached).

I have gone through various  articles to fix this, found most frequent solution as to uncomment the "extension=php_intl.dll" in php.ini file. But still it is not work. Also tried with restarting XAMPP after this and I am using Mac.

Please help me on this, I am wasting hours of time behind this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `extension=intl.so` instead of dll (since dll is windows only)

Comment: Yes tried that, still isnt working

Comment: @KabirUlAlthamash, if you are using XAMPP for Windows you will use `.dll`. You'd use `.so` for OSX and Linux. Do you have the `intl` extension installed?

Comment: @KabirUlAlthamash hope this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am too late, but this can help someone else. It clearly shows that your configuration missing extension. Go to your php.ini file and enable the extension = php_intl.dll by removing the ; before it. And re-run the installation.

Found this video which through which I installed it on my machine-
https://webarchers.com/installing-magento-2-on-xampp-got-stuck-at-51/