# ldap is missing from system when installing adldap2 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

firstly, im trying to install package inside the laravel composer using "composer install", but then it returns an error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.8 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.1 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.0 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.1 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.2 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.3 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.4 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.5 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.6 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2-laravel v6.0.7 requires adldap2/adldap2 ^10.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v10.0.0, v10.0.1, v10.0.10, v10.0.11, v10.0.2, v10.0.3, v10.0.4, v10.0.5, v10.0.6, v10.0.7, v10.0.8, v10.0.9, v10.1.0, v10.1.1].
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.1.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.1.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.9 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.8 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.7 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.6 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.5 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.4 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.3 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.11 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.10 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v10.0.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension ldap is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for adldap2/adldap2-laravel ^6.0 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2-laravel[v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.0.5, v6.0.6, v6.0.7, v6.0.8].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tried to run "composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel" too, but the returning is still the same. How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have the ldap extenstion enabled in php.ini?

Comment: looks like not, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Take a look at this SO thread. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl

Comment: hey, that helped me a lot! thank you

Comment: No Problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

The problem depends to the fact you don't have the ***ldap php library*** installed in your system.

If you are running Ubuntu you can solve with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-ldap
```