# Fatal Error on HeadTitle viewer without I18n\Translator module

Tags: php, zend-framework

Started zend framework 3 by installing the skeleton, when I run the app it crashes giving the fatal error below:-

```
Fatal error: Method Zend\View\Helper\HeadTitle::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught 
Zend\I18n\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException: Zend\I18n\Translator component requires the intl PHP 
extension in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample-crud\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml on line 0
```

I think I miss some extensions and I dont know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message is clear about it:

> Zend\I18n\Translator component requires the **intl** PHP 
>   extension

So you need to [enable intl PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850253/1320081).