# codeigniter 4, installation with composer problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-extension, intl

I'm new to Codeigniter and i want to ask why when i want to install CI 4 with composer it resulted

```
  Problem 1
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework 4.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for codeigniter4/framework ^4 -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2].
```

But i already uncommend the intl extension on php.ini (I'm using XAMPP)

I already tried to find answers but i can't find it. if you guys have opinion on what's going on please let me know. Thank youu

Answer (score 3):

If you are using php version 5.6 or below

`;extension=php_intl.dll` Remove semicolon from the line in php.ini file

If php 7 or above

Remove semicolon from the line `;extension=intl` in php.ini

***Once you updated php.ini restart XAMPP/WAMP***

Comment: There is no ;extension=intl but there is ;extension=php_intl.dll; and i already remove the semicolom, still it won't work

Comment: Only a little precisation: the extension syntax "extension=php_<ext>.dll" (in Windows) or "extension=<ext>.so" (in Linux) into the PHP configuration file, I think changed into "extension=<ext>" starting from PHP 7.2. I'm sure that in PHP 7.0 there is the legacy extension syntax.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 4 requires PHP >= 7.2.

The **composer.json** file of CodeIgniter 4 contains a php>=7.2 require; so you should see the requirements are not satisfy as first problem. But the strange thing is you have `extension=php_intl.dll;` into your PHP configuration file: from PHP version 7.2 you should have `extension=intl`. So, please check your PHP version you have into your XAMPP.

Then check that you have `C:\xampp\php` into your Windows PATH (or the right php directory path in your system).

Try to launch your **composer install**; if it give the same error, try to create a file **test.php** into your webroot, containings

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Open the **test.php** page on your local web server with the browser and search for **Internationalization support**. If you do not find this information, it means that extension is not active.

In this case, give a look if you have edit the right PHP.INI. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl) for the right setting of extension with XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run composer with the flag **--ignore-platform-reqs** to force the instalation, but be aware to solve dependency to run your project.

(I use this flag to install when the server runs on docker with different specifications than host)