# cakePHP:Tried running this code in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\bin>cake bake migration_snapshot Initial
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Exception: Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency
In [C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php, line 202]

2021-02-09 08:52:48 Error: [Cake\Database\Exception\MissingExtensionException] Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php on line 202
Exception Attributes: array (
  'driver' => 'Cake\\Database\\Driver\\Mysql',
)
Stack Trace:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php:142
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\ConnectionRegistry.php:90
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\ObjectRegistry.php:110
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\ConnectionManager.php:212
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\migrations\src\Command\BakeMigrationSnapshotCommand.php:122
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\migrations\src\Command\BakeMigrationSnapshotCommand.php:55
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\migrations\src\Command\BakeSimpleMigrationCommand.php:91
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\BaseCommand.php:179
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\CommandRunner.php:336
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\CommandRunner.php:172
- C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\bin\cake.php:12
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I enable PHP Extension intl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

Comment: Looks like your PHP config is trying to load the `intl` module *twice* and not load the MySQL module at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have two different versions of php on your machine.
cake bake should read the php extensions from xamp's php version i.e C:\xampp\php.