# How to solve the issue - please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities on windows

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5, pimcore-datahub

I am trying to install Pimcore's skeleton package on windows[AzureVM]. But facing issue called
"The Symfony\Polyfill\Intl\Icu\Locale::getPrimaryLanguage() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities."
I did configuration which is required but stucked here.
I configured path of document root in xampp -> Apache -> Config -> httpd.
Even try to find its solution somewhere on internet but can't find exact solution.
It would be great help for me.

I am tring to open admin interface of Pimcore.

[image: Here is screenshot message of error]

I am completely new in this field so please help like that.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed Pimcore then you can just enable Intl as @Archana recommended
[how can I enable PHP Extension intl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

It is recommended to check server requirements before to install:

```
bin/console pimcore:system:requirements:check
```

See documentation:
https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Requirements/