# rouble with CodeIgniter framework - Issue with 'ext-intl' extension

Tags: php, composer-php, codeigniter-4

I try to create a ci4 project via Composer and this message has appeared "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, ..., v4.3.7] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
- Root composer.json requires codeigniter4/framework ^4.0 -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, ..., v4.3.7].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` to temporarily ignore these required extensions." and when I enable the intl extension in php.ini it not work also

I try to create ci4 project and via composer and this doesn't work

Comment: "this doesn't work" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how can I enable PHP Extension intl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

Answer (score 0):

Open `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and uncomment
`;extension=intl` to `extension=intl`

Comment: I did that but it did not work and this has appeared "                               
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\intl (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\intl (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Can you try latest XAMPP, I'm using XAMPP with PHP 8.1.6 and it work. Hope it help.

Comment: I use it with php 8.1.10

Comment: I just install XAMPP with PHP 8.1.10 and got php_intl.dll: https://imgur.com/Sw1zIdd
I think you need reinstall XAMPP and double check folder pathtoxampp\php\ext\ to make sure it have file php_intl.dll

Comment: or you can try `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` to force it install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).