# PHP Fatal error: Class Bundle\\Controller\\Symfony\\Component\\Intl\\Intl not found

Tags: php, symfony, intl

What I Need

- i  Need To convert country code to currency Symbol.

  ```
   like for USD => $.
  ```
- i Need to convert Currency code to currency symbol.

Code

controller

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\CurrencyBundle;
class EventDetailController extends Controller
{
          $currency = $data[0]['currency'];
          $Currency= USD

       Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('USD'); 
}
```

Error

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Acme\\biztradeshowsBundle\\Controller\\Symfony\\Component\\Intl\\Intl' not found in /home/indiamart/public_html/10into/src/Acme/biztradeshowsBundle/Controller/EventDetailController.php on line 180
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write `use` statement:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\CurrencyBundle;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

class EventDetailController extends Controller
{
    $currency = $data[0]['currency'];
    $Currency= USD

    Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('USD'); 
}
```

or write your FQCN with leading slash:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\CurrencyBundle;

class EventDetailController extends Controller
{
    $currency = $data[0]['currency'];
    $Currency= USD

    \Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('USD'); 
}
```

Comment: error  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ResourceBundle' not found in /home/indiamart/public_html/10into/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/ResourceBundle/Reader/BinaryBundleReader.php on line 31

Comment: It is another problem:-) You can start new topic for that.
But I need to ask you: did you read http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html ? Your problem is in Intl component. Maybe you didn't install php-intl extensions properly.

Comment: how t check php-intln install properly

Comment: i have already install intln in bundle path is vendor->symphony->component ->resource bundle->reader->binaybundleraeder.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Disable `imap.so` to not confuse you. If PHP doesn't fail after warning then empty string means that you don't have `intl` installed. Did your Apache and PHP use the same instance of PHP?

Comment: Add your own table into DB (if you need many countries) or just define array in your class.

Comment: thank you finally after hard work i made th job done

Comment: michael i have simple issue intln is not working with currency euro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465720/how-to-format-the-currency-symbol-in-twig

Comment: please give some i have found bug in this country currency suugest how t check all country currency is ok in php